# Sefer of Jewish Philosophy

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, jewish-books

Is there any sefer which goes through the various philosophical issues according, and explains the opinion of the Jewish philosophers? (Example what is space; according to the Rambam, Rasag... What is the soul according to .....)

Comment: Are you thinking about something along the lines of Maimonides Confrontation with Mysticism but broader than rambam vs. judah halevi?

Comment: Yes something like that but would cover the major chokrim (and mekubalim if possible)

Comment: the closest thing I can think of is the Cambridge Companion to Jewish Philosophy. You'll be pleasantly surprised if you Google it. It's not an x said y on z topic and a said b, but it's a broad strokes survey that could serve as a good jumping off point.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Daas-Torah-Sourcebook-Daniel-Eidensohn/dp/B002LDA71Q